# DRF nested model serializer not included in Metadata

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Can't figure out why an OPTIONS request isn't including the writable nested model serializer or its inner fields.

```
class CustomerProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    description = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.description')

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerTemplate
        fields = ('id', 'description', 'quantity', 'unit',)


class CustomerDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = CustomerProductsSerializer(
        source='customertemplate_customer', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'products')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'name')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        ...
```

Current result of OPTIONS request:

```
{
    "name": "Customer Instance",
    "description": "",
    "renders": [
        "application/json",
        "text/html"
    ],
    "parses": [
        "application/json",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "multipart/form-data"
    ],
    "actions": {
        "PUT": {
            "id": {
                "type": "integer",
                "required": false,
                "read_only": true,
                "label": "ID"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": false,
                "read_only": true,
                "label": "Name"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Desired result of OPTIONS request would include `products` and the details of its inner fields:

```
"products" : {
    "type": "nested object",
    "required": false,
    "read_only": false,
    "children": {
        ...
    }
}
```

How would you go about adding the `products` field and its inner fields to the Metadata?

According to this [comment chain](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2915), it's been supported for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a mixin to allow for multiple serializers on one viewset.

```
class MultiSerializerMixin(object):
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action in self.serializers:
            return self.serializers.get(self.action, None)
        else:
            return super(MultiSerializerMixin, self).get_serializer_class()
```

I included a dictionary in my viewset to determine which serializer to use

```
serializers = {
    'list': CustomerListSerializer,
    'retrieve': CustomerDetailSerializer,
    'update': CustomerDetailSerializer,
    'partial_update': CustomerDetailSerializer,
}
```

The `OPTIONS` request uses the base metadata class `SimpleMetadata`. When  `SimpleMetadata().determine_actions()` is called the serializer is determined by `view.get_serializer()` which was returning the incorrect serializer and giving me all the actions for `GET` rather than `PUT`.